# count up unique list in list in Python

Tags: python, list, count

How can I count up every list in list in python?
I especially want to know how many of them are in common.

example:

```
list=[["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "A", "b"], ["B", "c", "C"],["a", "b", "c"]]
```

wanted output:

```
 value            counts
["a", "b", "c"]   2
["a", "A", "b"]   1
["B", "c", "C"]   1
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the required format? Should it be in dataframe or in some file? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You need a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: @pistol2myhead thanks. and I don't really care of the format of output actually, and i've tried Counter already.

Comment: Counter counts up only string I guess, doesnt work for every list in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't care about the format of the ouput, one option is to turn the sublists to `tuples` and then use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

The reasoning behind this is that `Counter` returns a hash table, and only immutable types are hashable, thus a workaround is to cast the sublist to `tuples` which *are immutable* unlike lists:

```
from collections import Counter

Counter([tuple(i) for i in l])
```

**Output**

```
Counter({('a', 'b', 'c'): 2, ('a', 'A', 'b'): 1, ('B', 'c', 'C'): 1})
```

Comment: it worked! thanks a lot, I figured out how to sort out its format by my self thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
list1 = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "A", "b"], ["B", "c", "C"],["a", "b", "c"]]
dictionary = Counter([tuple(i) for i in list1])
dd = pd.DataFrame(data={'list': list(dictionary.keys()),'count': list(dictionary.values())})
print(dd)
```

output:

```
        list  count
0  (a, b, c)      2
1  (a, A, b)      1
2  (B, c, C)      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Verbose option without dependencies:

```
lst = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "A", "b"], ["B", "c", "C"],["a", "b", "c"]]

res = {}
for array in lst:
    res.setdefault(tuple(array), list()).append(1)
```

It creates a dictionary where the sub list is the key, appending 1 each time it matches. Then transform the keys with the sum instead:

```
for k,v in res.items():
  res[k] = sum(v)
  # print(k, res[k])
```

Uncommenting the print line you get:

```
# ('a', 'b', 'c') 2
# ('a', 'A', 'b') 1
# ('B', 'c', 'C') 1
```

And `res` is now:

```
res #=> {('a', 'b', 'c'): 2, ('a', 'A', 'b'): 1, ('B', 'c', 'C'): 1}
```